# VS 2010 Beta1 "Historical Data Has not been Collected"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, beta

I am trying out the Historical Debugger in VS2010 Beta 1.

I have it turned on in the settings (at least I think I do), but when I try to examine objects the value is:

[Historical Data Has Not Been Collected]

Any Ideas how to get this to show the actual value?

Here is the code in question:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form

   {

       public Form1()

       {InitializeComponent();}

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

       {

           int numer = Int32.Parse(txtNumerator.Text) ;

           int denom = Int32.Parse(txtDemoninator.Text);

           float answer = DivideValues(numer, denom);

           txtAnswer.Text = answer.ToString();

       }

       private static float DivideValues(int numer, int denom)

       {

           float answer = numer / denom;

           return answer;

       }

   }
```

Comment: Figured some info out. 64 bit apps are not supported when launched from Visual Studio.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915(VS.100).aspx Historical Debugger supports postmortem debugging of 64-bit applications through Historical Debugger log files that were created by Test and Lab Manager but does not support debugging 64-bit applications that were launched from Visual Studio

However, when I lauch Historical Debugger from an  x86 machine it still performs the same (except when the debugger is in the direct call stack line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to work right you need to use the tree view in the Debug History Window.  The navigation arrows in the gutter seem to be more of a distraction than a help as it lets you get to areas that are not recorded.

Also, local variables are not recorded.  This is by design.